# Make a python module collection installable

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

We have a bunch of python scripts and want to make them installable using setuptools.

At the end importing our modules (after installing them) should work like this:

```
import companyname.productA.moduleA
```

Our first draft for the structure looks like this:

```
repository/
    setup.py
    companyname/
        __init__.py
        productA/
            moduleA/
                __init__.py
                moduleA.py
            moduleB/
                __init__.py
               moduleB.py
        productB/
            moduleA/
                __init__.py
                moduleA.py
            moduleB/
                __init__.py
               moduleB.py
```

This already seems to work, but it produce an installer for the whole collection. We also need to make installer for only product or even only a module, because not every customer will need everything. This seems to be possible by duplicating the whole repository and removing all products / modules which should not go into the installer. This approach doesn't sound very good to me, so my first question is: Is there a better way to this?

There's also another problem: How do handle version, author, maintainer?

setup.py currently looks like this:

```
setuptools.setup(
    version='...',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    maintainer='...',
    maintainer_email='...',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    ...
    )
```

Should we add all authors of all modules into setup.py? Is it possible to assign each module a version? Or do we need to make a combined version number of all moduls for setup.py? If yes, whats the best approach to do this?

Comment: If you want to keep them in the same namespace but as separate modules, there is no other way than to create a separate install package for each of them. Since you'd be creating separate install packages, you can have them in separate repositories with each having its own `setup.py` declaring its dependencies, versions, author info etc.

Comment: Will there be no problem with the dependencies, versions, author, ... when a customer installs multiple modules? Later we also want to use pip, will this approach also work there?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues as you'll effectively have different modules sharing the same root namespace - as log as they are not intruding on one another's namespace everything should be fine. One (in)famous example of such distribution in the Python world are all of the [`ruamel`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/) modules. To be fair, tho, the practice is frowned upon by some, considering it as an abuse of Python _modularity_ (as its hard to determine from the import alone if the import belongs to one or multiple external packages) but, to my knowledge, there is no official PEP condemning it.